how to use character variable in R to convert xts object to a matrix
I am trying to convert an xts object in R to a matrix, but cannot do it if I use a symbolic character variable. Here is my code.
library(quantmod)
tickertoget = "AAPL"
getSymbols(tickertoget, from = "2024-01-01", src="yahoo")
m1 = as.matrix(AAPL)
m2 = as.matrix(tickertoget)

When I run this code, m1 is a matrix, but m2 is not. If I simply ask R to show m2, here is what I get.
> m2
     [,1]  
[1,] "AAPL"

How can I use the variable "tickertoget" when I call as.matrix and get the same result as m1? Or, are there other functions that will work? I want to do this for many different tickers.

You should use get for returning the value of a named object:
m2 = as.matrix(get(tickertoget))
head(m2)
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2024-01-02    187.15    188.44   183.89     185.64    82488700      185.4034
2024-01-03    184.22    185.88   183.43     184.25    58414500      184.0152
2024-01-04    182.15    183.09   180.88     181.91    71983600      181.6782
2024-01-05    181.99    182.76   180.17     181.18    62303300      180.9491
2024-01-08    182.09    185.60   181.50     185.56    59144500      185.3235
2024-01-09    183.92    185.15   182.73     185.14    42841800      184.9041

For many different tickets you might consider using mget if you have a vector of names. See help file for details.
